# Are the storylines from The Wolverine movie and anime the same?

Tags: wolverine

Are [The Wolverine](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wolverine) movie (now on theaters) and the [2011 Wolverine anime series](http://wolverineanime.wikia.com/wiki/Wolverineanime_Wiki) based on the same plot?
From the trailers I can tell they definitely look similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they're different. The settings and some of the characters are the same but the overall plot isn't.

The Marvel animated series Wolverine was based on the 1982 Chris Claremont and Frank Miller graphic novel of the same name. Both the anime and movie have characters "*Mariko*", "*Shingen*", "*Yukio*". Both also have Mariko in an arranged marriage, but only in the anime is where Mariko is Logan's girlfriend. There's also this giant samurai automaton in both the movie and anime.

The beginning of the anime has Logan and Mariko both in New York City where she's kidnapped. Whereas the movie has him in the woods following the events of "**X-Men: Last Stand**". It seems there's a lot of mutants in the anime that aren't in the movie, in particular, Kikyo, a mutant who can extend a sword out of his wrists, similar to Logan and Omega Red, a Russian biomedical experiment.

I've never read the original graphic novels, but according to [this blog post](http://www.jacehallshow.com/blog/20110923/is-wolverine-anime-truer-to-the-comic-than-the-movies/), the anime is more faithful to the original novels than the movie series.